# return value subscribe directly into canActivate auth guard

Tags: angular, asynchronous, auth-guard

Below are my code, what im tring to do is im trying to get return value directly into canActivate return, but the problem is it will run the checking first before run "this._authService.isAdmin(token)" method. i know it like that because of async. But how to prevent that? i already run of idea. thanks in advance.

i already try putting that method on construtor but the result still same.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthenticationService } from "../_services/authentication.service";

@Injectable()
export class AdminGuard implements CanActivate  {

  isAdmin: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private _authService: AuthenticationService,
    private router: Router) {
  }

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

  var token = this._authService.getJwtToken();
  this._authService.isAdmin(token).subscribe(
     res => {
            //res will return true or false value
            this.isAdmin = res;
     }
  );

  if(this.isAdmin){
    return true;
  }
  this.router.navigate(['/']);
  return false;

  }
}
```

Comment: @sn42, thank for this ref..it working.. i could not find the correct keyword for this porblem before this

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pipeable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md) for this:

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  let token = this._authService.getJwtToken();
  return this._authService.isAdmin(token).pipe(
    tap(isAdmin => {
      if (isAdmin) {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      }
    })
  );
}

// Usage:
canActivate.subscribe(value => {
  // do something...
});
```

Note that the [tap](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/tap.ts) operator simply performs a "side effect task". The returned observable from the `tap` operator is the same as the one before it. Now the `if isAdmin` check within the tap operator is only evaluated once the isAdmin observable emits an event.